# Javascript extracting values from strings -- stock and company names

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have two strings that i would like to extract specific strings from.

```
var companyString1;
var companyName1;

var companyString2;
var companyName2;

var stockString1 = "STOCKDETAILS:TWEETS:FB:Facebook Inc.";

var stockString2 = "I have returned -- Facebook Inc. (FB) -- stock back.";

companySymbol1 = ? //would like this to be "FB"
companyName1 = ? //would like this to be "Facebook Inc."
companySymbol2 = ? //would like this to be "FB"
companyName2 = ? //would like this to be "Facebook Inc."
```

What is regex i can apply to stockSTring1 to extract "FB" (into companySymbol1 var) and "Facebook Inc." (into companyName1 var). Similarly i want to extract "FB" (into companySymbol2 var) and "Facebook Inc." (into companyName2 var) fro stockString2.

The format of stockString1, stockString2 will be guaranteed to be consistent fro source -- so you can assume there could be other symbols and names (e.g. GOOG/Google Inc, MSFT/Microsoft Corp. etc)

Truly appreciate any help.

Comment: So you have not tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with `split`, and one regular expression just to chop off the closing `)` in the second case:

```js
function getStock(s) {
    var parts = s.split(/\)? -- /);
    if (parts.length < 2) { // other format
        return s.split(':').slice(2, 4);
    }
    return parts[1].split(' (').reverse();
}

var stockString1 = "STOCKDETAILS:TWEETS:FB:Facebook Inc.";
var stockString2 = "I have returned -- Facebook Inc. (FB) -- stock back.";

var [companySymbol1, companyName1] = getStock(stockString1);
var [companySymbol2, companyName2] = getStock(stockString2);

console.log(companySymbol1, companyName1);
console.log(companySymbol2, companyName2);
```